# How to configure Spring OpenAPI UI behind Kong

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, kong, springdoc

I have a Spring Boot application and I'm using Kong as an API Gateway.

I would like to document my app's REST API with SpringDoc OpenAPI.

Everything works great locally, when I run my Spring Boot app as a standalone, but I'm facing a problem when accessing the Swagger/OpenAPI UI behind Kong.

This is my kong.yml:

```
services:
 - name: foo
   url: http://localhost:9000/foo
   routes:
   - name: foo-route
     paths:
      - /local/api/foo
     methods:
     - GET
     - POST
     - PUT
     - OPTIONS
     - DELETE
     - PATCH
     - HEAD
```

Assume that kong is on port 8000, and my Spring App is on port 9000.

When I hit Kong at `http://localhost:8000/local/api/foo/swagger-ui.html`, I get redirected to `http://localhost:8000/foo/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/foo/v3/api-docs/swagger-config`, which is the wrong path.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: you did any UI redirection through kong ?. its changing the browser url. How to preserve the kong domain on address bar ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution!

On the Spring Boot side, since I'm using a version higher than 2.2, all is needed is the following bean:

```
@Bean
ForwardedHeaderFilter forwardedHeaderFilter() {
    return new ForwardedHeaderFilter();
}
```

and this configuration:

```
server:
  forward-headers-strategy: framework
```

On the Kong side, since I'm using an outdated version (2.0.3), I need to add the following plugin to my `kong.yml` configuration file:

```
plugins:     
 - name: request-transformer
   service: foo
   config:
    add:
     headers:
      - x-forwarded-prefix:/local/api/foo
```

from my understanding, this is not needed in newer Kong versions: as long as the host has a trusted ip, the header `x-forwarded-prefix` will be added automatically.